# get weight from GATT characteristics value in react-native-ble-plx

Tags: android, react-native, android-bluetooth, react-native-ble-plx

I am developing an react-native app that gets the weight value of a scale(MI SCALE2) that supports Bluetooth.(I have no knowledge of bluetooth.)

---

// version

"react-native": "0.66.1",

"react-native-ble-plx": "https://github.com/below/react-native-ble-plx",

---

I was able to get these values ​​when I got on the scale.

```json
# feature
{"data": [33, 0, 0, 0], "type": "Buffer"}

# Weight
{"data": [2, 156, 74, 178, 7, 1, 7, 22, 33, 1], "type": "Buffer"}
{"data": [2, 156, 74, 178, 7, 1, 7, 22, 33, 1], "type": "Buffer"}
{"data": [2, 156, 74, 178, 7, 1, 7, 22, 33, 1], "type": "Buffer"}
{"data": [2, 156, 74, 178, 7, 1, 7, 22, 33, 2], "type": "Buffer"}
{"data": [2, 156, 74, 178, 7, 1, 7, 22, 33, 2], "type": "Buffer"}
{"data": [34, 156, 74, 178, 7, 1, 7, 22, 33, 2], "type": "Buffer"}
{"data": [162, 156, 74, 178, 7, 1, 7, 22, 33, 6], "type": "Buffer"}
```

After reading the Q&A in several places, I know that it is necessary to combine the value of the feature with the value of the weight array.

I want to know how to get the weight value from my result like "94.9kg, 95.5kg, ..."

Below is the code I wrote.

```js
manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error : ' + error);
        return;
      }

      console.log(device.name);

      if (device.name === 'MI SCALE2') {
        console.log('detected!!');
        manager.stopDeviceScan();
        device
          .connect()
          .then(device => {
            return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
          })
          .then(device => {
            return device.services();
          })
          .then(services => {
            const result = services.filter(id => id.uuid.indexOf('181d') != -1); // 181d is Weight Scale -> org.bluetooth.service.weight_scale;
            return result[0].characteristics();
          })
          .then(characters => {
            const resultDateObject = characters.filter(
              data => data.uuid.indexOf('2a2b') != -1, // 2a2b is Current Time -> org.bluetooth.characteristic.current_time;
            );
            const resultWeightFeature = characters.filter(
              data => data.uuid.indexOf('2a9e') != -1, // 2a9e is Weight Scale Feature -> org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_scale_feature
            );
            const resultWeight = characters.filter(
              data => data.uuid.indexOf('2a9d') != -1, // 2a9d is Weight Measurement -> org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_measurement;
            );
            const resultPosition2D = characters.filter(
              data => data.uuid.indexOf('2a2f') != -1, // 2a2f is Position 2D -> org.bluetooth.characteristic.position_2d;
            );
            
            // const DeviceID = resultWeightFeature[0].deviceID;
            // const ServiceUUID = resultWeightFeature[0].serviceUUID;
            // const DateCharacterUUID = resultDateObject[0].uuid;
            // const WeightFeatureCharacterUUID = resultWeightFeature[0].uuid;
            // const WeightCharacterUUID = resultWeight[0].uuid;
            // const PositionCharacterUUID = resultPosition2D[0].uuid;

            resultWeight[0].monitor((error, characteristic) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log('error:::::', error);
                return;
              }
              let your_bytes = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
              console.log(your_bytes);
            })
            return resultWeightFeature[0].read();

          }).then(feature => {
            let feature_bytes = Buffer.from(feature.value, "base64");
            console.log('feature.value');
            console.log(feature_bytes);
          })
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your Code, your weight scale makes use of Bluetooth [Weight Scale Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/de/specifications/specs/weight-scale-profile/) and [Weight Scale Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/de/specifications/specs/weight-scale-service/).
The data you find in the corresponding characteristics needs to be interpreted as described in [Personal Health Devices Transcoding](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/PHD_Transcoding_WP_v16.pdf)

Edit:
You can find more information on the data structure here:
[GATT Specification Supplement 5](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/gatt-specification-supplement-5/)

example:

Feature([33,0,0,0]) => 0x00000011 => ...00 0010 0001 =>

| value | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Time Stamp Supported: True |
| 0 | Multiple Users Supported: False |
| 0 | BMI Supported: False |
| 0100 | Weight Measurement Resolution: Resolution of 0.05 kg or 0.1 lb |
| 000 | Height Measurement Resolution: Not specified |

Weight = [34, 156, 74, 178, 7, 1, 7, 22, 33, 2]
=>       0x22 0x9c 0x4a 0xb2 0x07 0x01 0x07 0x16 0x21 0x02

First byte is a flags field => 0x22 => 0010 0010

| value | description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Measurement Units: SI |
| 1 | Time Stamp present: True |
| 0 | User ID present: False |
| 0 | BMI and Height present: False |
| 0010 | Reserved for Future Use |

Weight in kilograms with resolution 0.005 (uint16) => 0x4a9c => 95,5 kg

Time Stamp 0xb2 0x07 0x01 0x07 0x16 0x21 0x02

year(uint16)   => 0x07b2 => 1970

month(uint8)   => 0x01   => 1

day(uint8)     => 0x07   => 7

hours(uint8)   => 0x16   => 22

minutes(uint8) => 0x21   => 33

seconds(uint8) => 0x02   => 2

date 1970-01-07T22:33:02

Comment: Yes, you are right.
Actually, I've seen the document you suggested a few times, but it's hard to understand for me.
I'm not sure how to match the Feature([33,0,0,0]) I got with the table on page 47 of the document.
But luckily I did figure out how to calculate my measurements.
Weight = [34, 156, 74, 178, 7, 1, 7, 22, 33, 2]
I think 34 mean is final weight result status code.(2 is measuring)
and (Weight[2] * 256 + Weight[1]) * 0.005 was exactly the value of my weight. 
But I still don't know why that is correct even looking at the documentation.
If it's ok can you briefly explain?

Comment: Edit answer and add an example

Comment: Your example and explanation gave me the confidence to study further. thank you.